# Handling Boundary Conditions in OpenCL/CUDA

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

Given a 3D uniform grid, I would like to set the values of the border cells relative to the values of their nearest neighbor inside the grid. E.g., given a 10x10x10 grid, for a voxel at coordinate (0, 8, 8), I'd like to set a value as follows : *val(0, 8, 8)=a*val(1,8,8)*.

Since, *a* could be **any** real number, I do not think texture + samplers can be used in this case. In addition, the method should work on normal buffers as well.

Also, since a boundary voxel coordinate could be either part of the grid's corner, edge, or face, 26 (= 8 + 12 + 6) different choices for looking up the nearest neighbor exist (e.g. if the coordinate was at (0,0,0) its nearest neighbor insided the grid would be (1, 1, 1)). So there is a lot of potential branching.

Is there a "elegant" way to accomplish this in OpenCL/CUDA? Also, is it advisable to handle boundary using a seperate kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most usual way of handling borders in CUDA is to check for all possible border conditions and act accordingly, that is:

- If "this element" is out of bounds, then `return` (this is very useful in CUDA, where you will probably launch more threads than strictly necessary, so the extra threads must exit early in order to avoid writing on out-of-bounds memory).
- If "this element" is at/near left border (minimum x) then do special operations for left border.
- Same for right, up, down (and front and back, in 3D) borders.

Fortunately, on most occasions you can use max/min to simplify these operations, so you avoid too many ifs. I like to use an expression of this form:

```
source_pixel_x = max(0, min(thread_2D_pos.x + j, MAX_X));
source_pixel_y = ... // you get the idea
```

The result of these expressions is always bound between 0 and some MAX, thus clamping the out_of_bounds source pixels to the border pixels.

*EDIT: As commented by DarkZeros, it is easier (and less error prone) to use the clamp() function. Not only it checks both min and max, it also allows vector types like float3 and clamps each dimension separately. See: [clamp](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/clamp.html)*

Here is an example I did as an exercise, a 2D gaussian blur:

```
__global__
void gaussian_blur(const unsigned char* const inputChannel,
                   unsigned char* const outputChannel,
                   int numRows, int numCols,
                   const float* const filter, const int filterWidth)
{
  const int2 thread_2D_pos = make_int2( blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x,
                                        blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y);
  const int thread_1D_pos = thread_2D_pos.y * numCols + thread_2D_pos.x;

  if (thread_2D_pos.x >= numCols || thread_2D_pos.y >= numRows)
  {
      return;  // "this output pixel" is out-of-bounds. Do not compute
  }

  int j, k, jn, kn, filterIndex = 0;
  float value = 0.0;
  int2 pixel_2D_pos;
  int pixel_1D_pos;

  // Now we'll process input pixels.
  // Note the use of max(0, min(thread_2D_pos.x + j, numCols-1)),
  // which is a way to clamp the coordinates to the borders.
  for(k = -filterWidth/2; k <= filterWidth/2; ++k)
  {
      pixel_2D_pos.y = max(0, min(thread_2D_pos.y + k, numRows-1));
      for(j = -filterWidth/2; j <= filterWidth/2; ++j,++filterIndex)
      {
          pixel_2D_pos.x = max(0, min(thread_2D_pos.x + j, numCols-1));
          pixel_1D_pos =  pixel_2D_pos.y * numCols + pixel_2D_pos.x;

          value += ((float)(inputChannel[pixel_1D_pos])) * filter[filterIndex];
      }
  }

    outputChannel[thread_1D_pos] = (unsigned char)value;
}
```

Comment: I would use `clamp(val, min, max)` Which does the min() and max() together.

Comment: Good one, @DarkZeros. Looks like I'm too fond of my old ways. Indeed clamp() is a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCL you could use `Image3d` to handle your 3d grid. Boundary handling could be achived with a sampler and a specific adress mode:

> - CLK_ADDRESS_REPEAT - out-of-range image coordinates are wrapped to the valid range. This address mode can only be used with normalized coordinates. If normalized coordinates are not used, this addressing mode may generate image coordinates that are undefined.
> - CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE - out-of-range image coordinates are clamped to the extent.
> - CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP32 - out-of-range image coordinates will return a border color. The border color is (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) if image channel order is CL_A, CL_INTENSITY, CL_RA, CL_ARGB, CL_BGRA or CL_RGBA and is (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) if image channel order is CL_R, CL_RG, CL_RGB or CL_LUMINANCE.
> - CLK_ADDRESS_NONE - for this address mode the programmer guarantees that the image coordinates used to sample elements of the image refer to a location inside the image; otherwise the results are undefined.

Additionally you can define the filter mode for the interpolation (nearest neighbor or linear).

Does this fit your needs? Otherwise, please give us more detail about you data and its boundary requirements.

Comment: Sorry for not being very specific (I updated my question), unfortunately, I do not think I can use textures.

Comment: Just for clarification: you want to extrapolate your boundary values from your nearest inner values? Your data does not feed the - lets say - "hull" values, but only the inner ones. In this case it might be useful to use a linear interpolation/extrapolation-scheme throughout your whole data set. Aside from some optimization code, there is no direct OpenCL library support for your application. Well, of course you could use code like `float4 x = f * (float4) a + (1-f) * (float4) b` for linear interpolation between _a_ and _b_

Comment: Not necessarily extrapolate. Basically, given a coordinate (global id `id`), if that coordinate is on the border (boundary) of the grid (e.g. `id.x == 0` means the coordinate is on the left border of the grid), then I'd like to know which is the closest coordinate that is not a border coordinate, so that I could fetch the value at that position, do some operations on it and store it at the border coordinate's location. I want to write a fluid simulation, for the boundary velocities on the grid I need the velocity value at the closest "inner" cell, multiply it with -1 and store it at the border

Comment: I guess, your problem is not a 3d problem as such. The nearest coordinate in each dimension is independent from the number of dimensions. So for 1D-case the nearest coordinate for c = 0 is 1. And for c = max the nearest coordinate is max-1. This is valid in each dimension. You could use a min/max-query like `float nearest = max(1, min(n-1,x))`. OpenCL provides min-max-functions which operate component-wise. This scheme should be adapted to fit your grid data (sorry for the remaining work).

Comment: Better solution of course is: `float nearest = clamp(x,1, n-1)` (see above answer)